# Sharepoint Designer XLST XSL IF/Choose Statement

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code I'm using in SharePoint Designer:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number((ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(ddwrt:Today())))- (ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(@Date_x0020_only))))) div 864000000000) &gt;  7 div 864000000000 and &lt;= 14 div 864000000000">
        <h2> <strong><span style="font-size: 8pt"> WEEK 1 </span></strong>
            <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:whitespace-preserve="yes" xml:space="preserve"> </xsl:text>
        </h2>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

It works if I take out the `&lt;= 14 div 864000000000` part but I'm essentially trying to label something if it's aged between 7 and <=14 days but can't seem to get this to work.

Here is the error:

```
SharePoint Designer cannot render the XSLT in this Data View. Try to undo your changes or re-insert the Data View.

Failed setting processor stylesheet : 0x80004005 : Expression expected. number((ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(ddwrt:Today())))- (ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(@Date_x0020_only))))) div 864000000000) > 7 div 864000000000 and --><=<-- 14 div 864000000000
```

Updated:

Thanks you very much @matthias_h and @Jason Aller

So here is the code I ended up using:

```
<xsl:variable name="X"   

                        select="number((ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(
                        string(ddwrt:Today())))-(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(
                        string(@Date_x0020_only))))) div 864000000000)">

                </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:if test="$X &gt; 0 div 864000000000 and $X &lt;= 7 div 864000000000">

                <xsl:text> WEEK 1</xsl:text>

            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="$X &gt; 7 div 864000000000 and $X &lt;= 14 div 864000000000">

                <xsl:text> WEEK 2</xsl:text>

            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="$X &gt; 14 div 864000000000 and $X &lt;= 21 div 864000000000">

                <xsl:text> WEEK 3</xsl:text>

            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="$X &gt; 21 div 864000000000">

                <xsl:text> Escalation</xsl:text>

            </xsl:if>
```

So this works now in the Sharepoint designer preview section it looks like this:

11/7/2014 11:56 AM Escalation

11/7/2014 11:56 AM Escalation

11/7/2014 11:56 AM Escalation

11/26/2014 8:47 AM Escalation

12/18/2014 3:10 PM WEEK 2

But is showing up in the browser like this:

11/7/2014 11:56 AM  Escalation

11/7/2014 11:56 AM  Escalation

11/7/2014 11:56 AM  Escalation

11/26/2014 8:47 AM  Escalation

12/18/2014 3:10 PM  Escalation

12/29/2014 1:48 PM  Escalation

For some reason its calling them all escalation.  Any suggestions?

I really appreciate the help.

**Update 2**

Thanks @matthias_h

To answer your questions:

1.) Yes it is correct in SPD preview but incorrect in the browser.

2.) This is what the value is in SPD

11/7/2014 11:56 AM Escalation 0.00000000006134259259259259

11/7/2014 11:56 AM Escalation 0.00000000006134259259259259

11/7/2014 11:56 AM Escalation 0.00000000006134259259259259

11/26/2014 8:47 AM Escalation 0.00000000003935185185185185

12/18/2014 3:10 PM WEEK 2     0.000000000013888888888888888

These are what the values look like in Browser

11/7/2014 11:56 AM   Escalation  53

11/7/2014 11:56 AM   Escalation  53

11/7/2014 11:56 AM   Escalation  53

11/26/2014 8:47 AM   Escalation  34

12/18/2014 3:10 PM   Escalation  12

You think it has something to do with me divided everything by 864000000000?

The reason I did that is becuase it wasn't diplaying the date difference properly in the browser.

So I used this solution: http://sympmarc.com/2013/01/page/2/

Again thanks for the help

Comment: Could you please show more of the stylesheet and the XML input, too? This would enable us to reproduce your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered setting up a `<xsl:variable>` to hold the portion encased in `number()` and performing a comparison in the form `var > 7 and var <= 14`?

Comment: Two questions to understand the issue in the updated code - 1) is the preview output ok and only the browser output wrong and 2) what is the value of `$X`? Can you print it out with `<xsl:value-of select="$X/>' as test after it's declared and check if you get diff values on preview and browser?

Comment: Sorry @matthias_h Please see the original post update 2.  I'm new to this forum and am not sure how I can format text properly in the comment section.

Comment: Don't mind, no need for excuses. You can click `help` below the _Add Comment_ button to get info about formatting, and btw it's always better to add additional information to the original post instead as comment, so people can see the full question including updates instead of having to go to the comments. Also, it should be avoided to have extended discussion in comments and to use SO chat instead, but for using this feature you need a reputation of 20. I just check the update, but maybe it's better to add this as a new question because the first question is solved and this is a follow-up.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: the value of `$x` in the preview is `0.000000000013888888888888888`, and the same `$x` in the browser is `12` ?

Comment: Yes. It's apparently a weird issue with sharepoint designer and sharepoint server. The reason I made my formula using the 864,000,000,000 is because in the browser it would show up as the decimal value.  This is the original solution I used to fix the issue and might clarify the problem: http://sympmarc.com/2013/01/07/calculate-days-between-two-sharepoint-list-dates-in-xsl/

Comment: If I don't need to use that method I would prefer not to but it seems to be my only solution.

Comment: I've checked the mentioned sharepoint links and can't give any advice as I'm more into xslt and not SP and would need more info (e.g. if it's possible to differentiate in SP between SPD view and browser view or, if not, if it would be ok to have the correct results only in browser view etc.), but I recommend the following: your xslt issue is already solved, now you have a specific SP problem. Put this in a _new question_ with a new specific title as now it's a diff issue. Then it's easier to get more attention that there is a new problem to solve as this question is already marked as answered

Comment: @matthias_h sounds like a plan. I appreciate all the help you've given me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test the full expression because of missing namespace and functions, but I think there is following syntactical error, just as example:

```
<xsl:when test="value &gt; 14 and &lt; 7">
```

should be

```
<xsl:when test="value &gt; 14 and value &lt; 7">
```

I suggest - for readability to have the expression in the number()  as variable, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="testString"   
      select="number((ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(
      string(ddwrt:Today())))-(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(
      string(@Date_x0020_only))))) div 864000000000)">
```

and then to check if

```
<xsl:when test="$testString &gt; 7 div 864000000000 
                and $testString &lt;= 14 div 864000000000">
```

will work.
Also, if you have no `xsl:otherwise` or other `xsl:when` cases, you could adjust to `xsl:if` instead.

Comment: wow.  Thanks @matthias_h

That was way easier then what I had.  I am a beginner when it comes to coding so forgive my formatting of code.

Here is what I ended up doing:

Tried to post the code but its too long.  I will edit my original post so you can see.

My new problem now though is that it works perfectly in sharepoint designer, that is when i see it in the preview section, but it says the same thing for each row in the browser.  All of them say escalation.  Is there something im doing wrong?